# How to kill asp .net session explicitly before timeout when user logs out from portal

Tags: asp.net, .net, session-state

In my application default session time-out is 20 minutes. When the user logs out from the portal before time-out is there any way to kill the session explicitly. The session state is configured to "inproc".

Application is launched on a portal and user can access the application and logs out from portal. Session state is still alive if he logs out before 20 minutes which consumes more memory and leads to performance degradation as there are multiple alive user sessions.

Based on authentication token from portal how can we explicitly identify current user session and how to kill it explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

If you call [`Session.Abandon()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon(v=vs.110).aspx) that will release anything stored for that session.

Comment: To use Session.Abandon() need to find out the perticular logged in session.How to find the particular user session based on userId

Comment: You shouldn't need to. When the user is logging out abandon the current session. The session you're abandoning will be the one for the user that is logging out.